# CSS 3 Spin not working

Tags: css, animation

Im using **webkit** as I'm mostly using *chrome* to preview.

The circles I made are not spinning (I am positive it's not an HTML issue.)

```css
#loader-wrapper {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 1000;
}

#loader {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
 
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 3px solid transparent;
 border-top-color: yellow;

 -webkit-animation: spin 1.5 infinite;
 animation: spin 1.5 infinite;
}

#loader:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 left:5px;
 right: 5px;
 bottom: 5px;
 
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 3px solid transparent;
 border-top-color: orange;

 -webkit-animation: spin 1.5 infinite;
 animation: spin 1.5 infinite;
}

#loader:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 left:15px;
 right: 15px;
 bottom: 15px;

 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 3px solid transparent;
 border-top-color: red;

 -webkit-animation: spin 1.5 infinite;
 animation: spin 1.5 infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
 0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}

 100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes spin {
 0%   {transform: rotate(0deg);}

 100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `s` of second in the `animation-duration`

```css
#loader-wrapper {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 1000;
}

#loader {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
 
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 3px solid transparent;
 border-top-color: yellow;

 -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s infinite;
 animation: spin 1.5s infinite;
}

#loader:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 left:5px;
 right: 5px;
 bottom: 5px;
 
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 3px solid transparent;
 border-top-color: orange;

 -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s infinite;
 animation: spin 1.5s infinite;
}

#loader:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 left:15px;
 right: 15px;
 bottom: 15px;

 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 3px solid transparent;
 border-top-color: red;

 -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s infinite;
 animation: spin 1.5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
 0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}

 100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes spin {
 0%   {transform: rotate(0deg);}

 100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="loader-wrapper">
<div id="loader">

</div>
</div>
```